# HOW TO: Remotely access Synology NAS on home LAN behind multiple routers?

Tags: router, lan, nas

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I split/share an internet connection with family members that live next door to my house.  I don't have/need/want cable, so they have the modem.  I have admin/config access to all components involved.

I have a NAS server on my end that I cannot figure out how to access from outside my LAN.  My network components are arranged thusly:

**Internet**
|
|
V
*[next door]*
  |
  |
  V
**ISP Cable Modem**
  |
  V
**Router**: D-Link DI-524
  |
  |
*[my house]*
  |
  |
  V
**Access Point**:  UBNT Nanostation (necessary for reliably strong WiFi signal from next door)
  |
  V
**Router**: Engenius ESR1221 (EXT)
  |
  V
**NAS**: Synology ds210j

It took me forever just to configure an internet connection to my house through all of those components, I'm maxing out my knowledge-level here.

I've worked on accessing the NAS, off & on, for months with no luck.  I've tried accessing different components (file server, ftp, vpn server, etc.), with SSL / without SSL, I've forwarded ports, DMZ'd inner router, DMZ'd the NAS, setup a dynDNS account.  All in such a disorderly fashion that some combination thereof may be the answer & I danced around it.

At any rate, I'm looking for an explanation of the networking concepts to do this (if one exists) that ignores what I've tried so far & focuses on the components involved.  Thank you!